# Data is not updating in database on update Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I just implement the `CRUD` in my Application , but UPDATE is not updating data in Database I `var_dump($user->name)` but it outputs nothing . Please take a look on the code and help me out.I am using Laravel 5.2 and Resource Controller.

PS : Edit is working fine e.g on this URL `http://localhost/pos/users/6/edit?id=6` I can populate the view fields with the required data but when I hit update nothing updates in Database.

**UserController:**

```
  public function edit($id)
        {
            $user = User::find($id);
            return view('user.update')->with('userToUpdate',$user);
        }

        /**
         * Update the specified resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $user = User::find($id);
            $user->name = Input::get('name');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = bcrypt(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();      
            return Redirect::to('/users')->with('message', 'User Updated');
        }
```

**UpdateView:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Update</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="PUT" action="{{ url('/users') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{!! $userToUpdate->name !!}">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{!! $userToUpdate->email !!}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{!! $userToUpdate->password !!}">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i>Update
                                </button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UserModel:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('/register', function(){
        return view('auth.register');
    })->middleware('isAdmin');
    Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController');

});
```

Comment: Using the PUT method in an HTML form is non-standard. I'm getting it to behave as a GET form when I try it.

Comment: @apokryfos PUT is for update , what else I can add ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the laravel docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#method-spoofing

> HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or DELETE routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the form.

However the Route::resource specifies that the update needs to use the PUT method. Therefore your form needs to be:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/users', $userToUpdate->id) }}">
     {!! csrf_field() !!}
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Comment: worked like a charm but explain this Point that in form tag you have used method = POST and then in hidden field Method = PUT I didn't got that ?

Comment: And 1 thing other as @Harry Loyd mentioned that action should be action="{{ url('/users', $userToUpdate->id) }} i.e pass the ID along with action otherwise it will not work I tried it!

Comment: HTML forms only support GET and POST. Laravel allows you to use the hidden field `_method` to simulate the rest of the HTTP "verbs" (PUT, PATCH,DELETE) (check https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers as to why this is needed).

Answer (score 3):

Is it because your not passing the user id when sending off the form? Try editing the form action from `{{ url('/users') }}` to `{{ url('/users', $userToUpdate->id) }}`.

Comment: Still not updating data in database @Harry Loyd

Comment: on var_dump($user) it displays nothing when I hit update @Harry Loyd

Comment: What happens if you var_dump($id) in the update function? is it still set to null?

Comment: OK not entirely sure what else it is. With var_dump() you should still see null printed out even if the variable is not set. Can you inspect element in your browser and double check that the form action URL is correct there?